# ./configure not seeing/finding boost header files

Tags: boost, compiler-construction, fedora, gearman

Trying to build gearman from the gearmand-0.33.tar.gz from Launchpad using bzr, on a Fedora 64 system.

doing the ./configure by tiself, as well as using the "-with-boost=/usr/include" param generates warnings an errors as the configure process can't seem to find/locate the boost header files.

we've removed/reinstalled the boost header files via "yum install boost*" as well

Any pointers will be tried!

Thanks

```
./configure
.
.
.
checking if more special flags are required for pthreads... no
checking for PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT... yes
checking for Boost headers version >= 1.39.0... yes
checking for Boost's header version... 1_41
checking for the toolset name used by Boost for g++... gcc44 -gcc
checking boost/program_options.hpp usability... no
checking boost/program_options.hpp presence... yes
configure: WARNING: boost/program_options.hpp: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: boost/program_options.hpp:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: boost/program_options.hpp: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: boost/program_options.hpp:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: boost/program_options.hpp: proceeding with the compiler's result
configure: WARNING:     ## -------------------------------------------------- ##
configure: WARNING:     ## Report this to https://bugs.launchpad.net/gearmand ##
configure: WARNING:     ## -------------------------------------------------- ##
checking for boost/program_options.hpp... no
configure: error: cannot find boost/program_options.hpp
```

Comment: you could check `configure.log` for detailed information.

Answer (score 11):

Just have dealt with this problem, installed gcc-c++ and that has resolved it

Comment: Thanks, worked for me too, but Id never have guessed

Comment: As we progress toward newer technologies, you might want to install `g++` instead. Question slightly outdated.

Answer (score 2):

The correct option is probably `--with-boost`, you should check that with `./configure -h`.

Also, check whether the directory `/usr/include/boost` exists, because that seems to be what it's looking for.

Furthermore, make sure you shouldn't be using `--with-boost-include=/usr/include` (and maybe also `--with-boost-libs` (or `-lib`)).

Comment: Hi Kenneth. Thanks for the reply. Turns out there was corrupted data in another part of the build process, which affected this part. Once I get everything building correctly, I'll repost to shut this one out.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using `--with-boost=/path/to/root` worked, where `/path/to/root` contains `include/boost`.

In other words, `--with-boost=/path/to/root/include` or `--with-boost=/path/to/root/include/boost` are both wrong.

I also set `--with-boost-libdir=/path/to/root/lib64`