# Cannot compile gearman - configure script fails

Tags: compilation, redhat, configure, gearman

My system is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.7 (Tikanga).

I am trying to run the configure script , and I am getting the following error:

```
checking for the toolset name used by Boost for g++... gcc41 -gcc
configure: Detected BOOST_ROOT; continuing with --with-boost=/raid/users/andrey/3rdParty/boost_1_47/
checking for Boost headers version >= 1.39.0... /users/andrey/3rdParty/boost_1_47/
checking for Boost's header version... 1_47
checking boost/program_options.hpp usability... no
checking boost/program_options.hpp presence... no
checking for boost/program_options.hpp... no
configure: error: cannot find boost/program_options.hpp
```

The documentation of configure says that boost is an optional package. So I tried to build it without boost:

```
  configure -with-boost=no
```

This does not run as well and returns the following error:

```
checking for assert... no
checking for the toolset name used by Boost for g++... gcc41 -gcc
configure: Detected BOOST_ROOT=/users/andrey/3rdParty/boost_1_47/, but overridden by --with-boost=no
checking for Boost headers version >= 1.39.0... no
```

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254898/configure-not-seeing-finding-boost-header-files) already, but it does not seem to help me.
Any idea?

Comment: I am having continued trouble compiling gearman on Centos 5.4 too. Are you sure /raid/users/andrey/VRA/3rdParty/boost_1_47/ contains boost headers (include), rather than boost libraries?

Comment: The correct flag is `--with-boost=no` (double dash).

You say that gives you another error, but you're not showing any errors, only a warning that the configure is using the `--with-boost=no`, which is exactly what you want... How does it fail when you disable boost?

Comment: Which version of Gearman are you attempting to compile?

Comment: @Diemuzi, frankly, I don't remember anymore. I was not quite satisfied with Gearman, so I decided to leave it alone.

Answer (score 2):

in debian/ubuntu/mint you can use :

```
apt-get   install  libboost-all-dev
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will not be able to check it, since I am not using Gearman anymore

Comment: libboost-all-dev is already the newest version and same error

Comment: for all kind of errors pls see: https://hasin.me/2013/10/30/installing-gearmand-libgearman-and-pecl-gearman-from-source/

Comment: The question starts with “My system is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.7 (Tikanga).” so an answer that states that a very different Linux distribution has a package is not all that helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I have met the same issue when building the gearmand from source. The issue was fixed after I installed the package boost-devel, which will place needed headers into /usr/include/boost. Thanks and hope this may help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will not be able to check it, since I am not using Gearman anymore

Answer (score 0):

Step "Installing Cygwin Package Dependencies needed for Gearman".
In addition to these packages:

```
gcc
gcc-c++
gcc-g++
make
libuuid1-devel
libiconv
```

if you did this you can:
reinstall cygwin and install this :

```
libuuid
boost
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will not be able to check it, since I am not using Gearman anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following command to solve this issue.

```
yum install boost*
```

If you are using centos or fedora or redhat then above command will work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will not be able to check it, since I am not using Gearman anymore